# Separar items en navbar BOOTSTRAP

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

quiero separar los items de mi navbar ya que quedaron todos juntos, y no encuentro la forma, la idea es que quede así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Me queda así :(
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm">
    <div class= "container-fluid">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="/img/VC-LOGO.png" alt="logo vi" width="100"></img> </a>
      <div  class="navbar-expand-sm"></div>
          <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
              <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#"></a>Home</li>
              <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#"></a>Servicios</li>
              <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#"></a>Skills</li>
              <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#"></a>Experiencia</li>
              <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#"></a>Contacto</li>
          </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
```

Comment: Ese es todo tu código ??

Comment: ¿Y el logo dónde debe quedar?

Answer (score 0):

He corregido un tanto tu código. El mayor problema es la distribución que le has dado, poner texto fuera de los links (por lo que nunca entras dentro del ), y eliminar el collapse sin controlarlo.

```html
<head>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-giJF6kkoqNQ00vy+HMDP7azOuL0xtbfIcaT9wjKHr8RbDVddVHyTfAAsrekwKmP1" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
            <img src="/img/VC-LOGO.png" alt="logo vi" width="100"></img>
        </a>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavAltMarkup">
            <div class="navbar-nav">
                <a class="nav-item nav-link text-muted" href="#">Home</a>
                <a class="nav-item nav-link text-muted" href="#">Services</a>
                <a class="nav-item nav-link text-muted" href="#">Skills</a>
                <a class="nav-item nav-link text-muted" href="#">Experiencie</a>
                <a class="nav-item nav-link text-muted" href="#">Contact</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.5.4/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-q2kxQ16AaE6UbzuKqyBE9/u/KzioAlnx2maXQHiDX9d4/zp8Ok3f+M7DPm+Ib6IU" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-pQQkAEnwaBkjpqZ8RU1fF1AKtTcHJwFl3pblpTlHXybJjHpMYo79HY3hIi4NKxyj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias :) de verdad, miil gracias. Y para moverlo a la izquierda como haría? solo quiero mover los items, no el logo

Comment: Tienes 2 formas, seguir usando Bootstrap, y moverlo donde quieras, o crear tu propio CSS. Recomendaria seguir usando bootstrap y acomodarlos. Pero eso debes buscarlo tu, por que ya varía del problema inicial que tenias. Podrías abrir otra pregunta, marcando esta respuesta, y (en mi caso) mañana llegaria a verla.

Comment: gracias excorpion, a voy a leer la docu :D

Comment: suerte compañero !!